Is Adoptium jdk8u412-b08 built products supported on RHEL7.4? Getting GLIC_2.28 error
Is Adoptium jdk8u412-b08 built products supported on RHEL7.4? Getting GLIBC_2.28 error.
Any suggestions to understand wht is wrong and how to fix it.
Same product works fine on Is Adoptium jdk8u412-b08 built products supported on RHEL7.4? Getting GLIBC_2.28 error.
Any suggestions to understand what is wrong and how to fix it.
Same product works fine on rhel8.


Is Adoptium jdk8u412-b08 built products supported on RHEL7.4?

Adoptium lists RHEL 7 as supported in a docker container.

Getting GLIBC_2.28 error

The error means: this binary was linked against GLIBC-2.28 or newer, and will not run on any system with earlier GLIBC version.
RHEL 8.4 has GLIBC 2.28, so RHEL 7.4 must have had something earlier (the same answer says that RHEL 7.9 used GLIBC 2.17).
Normally I use http://distrowatch.com to figure out which distribution shipped with which GLIBC version, but it currently gives me error 403.
P.S. You may wish to study this answer if you really must run on RHEL-7.4 system, but this is ill-advised (due to all the vulnerabilities which have since been fixed).
